# Trouble with draft c++ program made to initialise and return a customer

Tags: c++, struct

I have am creating a c++ program where A customer is able to be made initialised and returned....... yes you guessed right its for collage, below is my code that is being written with visual studio 2013. I have compiled with many errors (to many to list) that go above my knowledge as a entry level stack member. I need you to know that there are some parts of the code missing but not massive parts just some of the output info....and this is simply because its not the full program im half way through it and wanting to test what I have to make sure I'm remotely close to have it work and actually have it print to screen...and I am already aware of the tutorials google provides to help us but I spent a good 6 hours last night going into early hours of the morning looking at these and they don't tend to apply to what im doing all that well.

I would be thankful for someone patchwork what I have below, I find it hard to apply things from a description. again thank you wonderful people on stack!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string> using namespace std;


#include "Customer.h"
#define Customer

Customer* CreateCustomer (const string& name, const string& id, const string& pin=0);


Customer*  CreateCustomer(const string& name, const string& id, const string& pin) {
    Customer* customer = new Customer();
    customer->Name = name;
    customer->ID = id;
    customer->Pin = pin;
    customer->List[0].Name = "Mary Jones";
    customer->List[0].Id = "235718";
    customer->List[0].Pin = "5074";        
    customer->List[1].Name = "John Smith";
    customer->List[1].Id = "375864";
    customer->List[1].Pin = "3251";         
    customer->Enrolled = unit;   
    return customer; 
}


Customer* CreateCustomer(const string& name, const string& id, const string& pin = 1);


Customer*  CreateCustomer(const string& name, const string& id, const string& pin) {
    Customer* customer = new Customer();    
    customer->Name = name;
    customer->Id = id;
    customer->Id = pin;       
    customer->List[1].Name = "John Smith";
    customer->List[1].Id = "375864";
    customer->List[1].Pin = "3251";       
    customer->List = CreateCustomer;

    return customer; {     
}

int main() {    
    //test
    Customer* Mary = CreateCustomer("Mary Jones", "235718", "5074");    
    return 0; 
}
```

Allow me to show you my #include header file also...

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <string> using namespace std;

    #ifndef CUSTOMER_H
    #define CUSTOMER_H


    struct Customer {
         string Name;
         string Id;
         string Pin;
         CreateCustomer [10];
         int Enrolled; 
    };

    #endif
```

and when im all done i need it to action the below,

```
int main()
{
  Customer* Mary = CreateCustomer("Mary Jones", "235718", "5074");
  Customer* John = CreateCustomer("John Smith", "375864", "3251");
  Account* MaryAccount = CreateAccount(*Mary, "06-3121-10212357", "01/03/2014", 100);
  Account* JohnAccount = CreateAccount(*John, "06-3121-10213758", "10/03/2014");
  RecordWithdraw(MaryAccount, CreateTransaction("01/03/2014", "ATM Withdrawal", 50) );
  RecordDeposit(MaryAccount, CreateTransaction("02/03/2014", "Deposit", 90) );
  RecordWithdraw(MaryAccount, CreateTransaction("04/03/2014", "ATM Withdrawal", 150) );
  RecordDeposit(MaryAccount, CreateTransaction("05/03/2014", "Deposit", 20) );
  RecordWithdraw(MaryAccount, CreateTransaction("05/03/2014", "Withdraw", 100) );
  RecordWithdraw(MaryAccount, CreateTransaction("05/03/2014", "Withdraw", 50) );
  RecordDeposit(JohnAccount, CreateTransaction("11/03/2014", "Deposit", 20) );
  RecordDeposit(JohnAccount, CreateTransaction("12/03/2014", "Deposit", 80) );
  RecordWithdraw(JohnAccount, CreateTransaction("12/03/2014", "Withdraw", 50) );
  PrintReport(MaryAccount);
  PrintReport(JohnAccount);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In addition to the `#define Customer` indicated below, check the extra { after `customer->List = CreateCustomer;`. Also the `using namespace std;` placed among `#include` is a bad idea since it will affect the parsing of the header files included afterwards.

Comment: A default argument shall not be redeﬁned by a later declaration (not even to the same value)

Comment: ... and why are you declaring and defining twice the same function?

Comment: @jsantander thanks for your help in relation to what to remove....and as for declaring and defining twice well strangely enough my professor told me to do it.....

Comment: @yuan thanks for you help...sorry if i sound like a fool would you be so kind to show me a correction..i understand stack doesn't want discussion but rather answers so i hope this is not in breach. but either way thank you

Comment: There are just too many problems in your code. What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz that bad hey? im trying to achieve functions and structs that makes the int main down the bottem of my question work

Comment: OK, I've reformatted your main function, so it is readable. Now everything is clear, you want us to write the whole program for you. SO is not there for doing homework for other people but for answering **specific** questions. I'll write a partial answer that resolves the CreateCustomer issue, but then you should show an effort and try to write the `CreateAccount`, `RecordWithdraw`, `RecordDeposit` and `PrintReport` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing:

1. If you use `#define Customer` the preprocessor will be removing all the instances of the Customer identifier string... so the code the compiler will find will be like a gruyere cheese.
2. You cannot declare multiple times the same function with different default values
3. You cannot define multiple times the same function
4. Is a bad idea to initialize a std::string with a number. That will crash the program
5. There's an extra bracket in the line `return customer; {`
6. Is a bad (style) idea to have the `using namespace std;` in the middle of the `#include` directives... since it would affect the code parsed (from the headers) afterwards potentially resulting in surprising (and difficult to debug) problems.
7. The Customer struct contains an attribute without type or a type without attribute `CreateCustomer[10]`... which funnily enough has the same name as your repeating functions...

I'm sure there are more...

Comment: cheers for that I cant believe i missed all that jazz. thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

This would be the first steps towards your program.

BTW this is actually not the way this should be done in C++ but rather the way it is done in C. In C++ you would work with classes and member functions, but that's another story.

I've changed the following line:

```
Account* MaryAccount = CreateAccount(*Mary, "06-3121-10212357", "01/03/2014", 100);
```

into

```
Account* MaryAccount = CreateAccount(Mary, "06-3121-10212357", "01/03/2014", 100);
```

because it is a bad idea to store a complete copy of the `Mary` customer in the account whereas storing a pointer is simpler and more apporopriate in this case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std ;

struct Customer {
     string Name;
     string Id;
     string Pin;
};

struct Account {
  Customer *Customer ;
  string AccountNumber ;
  string AccountCreationDate ;
  int Balance ;
};


Customer* CreateCustomer(const string & name, const string & id, const string & pin)
{
  Customer *newcustomer = new Customer ;
  newcustomer->Id = id ;
  newcustomer->Name = name ;
  newcustomer->Pin = pin ;

  return newcustomer ;
}


Account *CreateAccount(Customer *customer, const string & accountnumber, const string & creationdate, int initialbalance)
{
  Account *newaccount = new Account ;
  newaccount->Customer = customer ;
  newaccount->AccountNumber = accountnumber ;
  newaccount->AccountCreationDate = creationdate ;
  newaccount->Balance = initialbalance ;
  return newaccount ;
}


int main()
{
  Customer* Mary = CreateCustomer("Mary Jones", "235718", "5074");
  Customer* John = CreateCustomer("John Smith", "375864", "3251");
  Account* MaryAccount = CreateAccount(Mary, "06-3121-10212357", "01/03/2014", 100);
  // ...
  return 0;
}
```